# Deserialize Json document when everything in source is an array, but target object type is not

Tags: c#, json, .net, serialization, .net-6.0

I have a JSON object where all properties are arrays regardless of if they really should be or not.

```
{
   "StringValue": ["mystringvalue"],
   "StringArrayValue": ["value1","value2"],
   "LongValue": [123]
}
```

Meanwhile, my class knows the types they should actually be

```
class MyClass {
   public string StringValue {get;set;}
   public string[] StringArrayValue {get;set;}
   public long LongValue {get;set;}
}
```

When I do JsonSerializer.Deserialize(jsondoc), it fails because it cannot convert the arrays to non-arrays. How can I have the deserializer pick the first value in the returned JSON data if the class type is not an array?

Comment: You can decorate your properties with a simple `JsonConverter<T>` that reads a token, verifies that the `[Token].Count() == 1` and returns `[Token].First.ToObject<T>();` in case it is. -- More work if you want to apply a JsonConverter to the class instead of the single Properties (since you also need to resolve the Contract *manually*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jimi had the right idea. Here is what I ended up with.

```
public class GetFirstElementJsonConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T>
{
    public override T? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartArray)
        {
            reader.Read();
            var elements = new List<T>();
            while (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndArray)
            {
                elements.Add(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(ref reader, options)!);

                reader.Read();
            }
            return elements.FirstOrDefault();
        }
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(ref reader, options);
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, options);
    }
}
```

And then apply it like:

```
class MyClass {
    [JsonConverter(typeof(GetFirstElementJsonConverter<string>))]
    public string StringValue {get;set;}
    public string[] StringArrayValue {get;set;}
    [JsonConverter(typeof(GetFirstElementJsonConverter<long>))]
    public long LongValue {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you  don't want to make things too complex, you can make an additional class for the Deserialization

```
class MyClassOriginalValue {
   public string[] StringValue {get;set;}
   public string[] StringArrayValue {get;set;}
   public long[] LongValue {get;set;}
   
   public MyClass GetMyClass()
   {
        return new MyClass
        {
            StringValue = this.StringValue?.FirstOrDefault(),
            StringArrayValue = this.StringArrayValue,
            LongValue = this.LongValue?.FirstOrDefault() ?? 0
        }
   }
}
```

Here my results:

```
void Main()
{
    var jsonOrig = $"{{" + 
       "\"StringValue\": [\"mystringvalue\"]," +
       "\"StringArrayValue\": [\"value1\",\"value2\"]," +
       "\"LongValue\": [123]" +
     "}";
    
    var originalJsonValue = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClassOriginalValue>(jsonOrig);
    
    var targetValue  = originalJsonValue.GetMyClass();
    
    Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(targetValue));
}
```

[image]

Comment: Compared to @IVSoftware solution, this also works if you cannot modify the original `MyClass` class.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to map the array values to a backing store that *is* an array, but add a getter-setter adapter that allows you to use the singular `StringValue` and `LongValue` properties transparently. The "original" singular get-set properties themselves will be ignored by Json per `[JsonIgnore]` attribute.

```
class MyClass
{
    [JsonPropertyName("StringValue")]
    public string[] StringValueBackingStore { get; set; } = new string[1];

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string StringValue
    {
        get => StringValueBackingStore.FirstOrDefault();
        set
        {
            if(StringValueBackingStore.Length == 1)
            {
                StringValueBackingStore[0] = value;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Assert(false, "Expecting array length of 1");
            }
        }
    }
    public string[] StringArrayValue { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("LongValue")]
    public long[] LongValueBackingStore { get; set; } = new long[1];

    [JsonIgnore]
    public long LongValue
    {
        get => LongValueBackingStore.FirstOrDefault();
        set
        {
            if (LongValueBackingStore.Length == 1)
            {
                LongValueBackingStore[0] = value;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Assert(false, "Expecting array length of 1");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**TEST SERDES**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var myClass = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(jsondoc);
    Console.WriteLine($"{myClass.StringValue} {myClass.LongValue} {string.Join(",", myClass.StringArrayValue)}");

    Console.WriteLine($"\n{JsonSerializer.Serialize(myClass)}");
}
```

[image: console]

Comment: thank you, I thought about this approach, but is a little tedious because the actual implementation has many properties and I have many different classes that all need to use this. Furthermore, I need to serialize the data back without the array type so the ignore actually causes a problem. I was hoping for a more generic solution.

Comment: I appreciate the additional details. Definitely my goal was to ensure that the `MyClass` data wouldn't be altered in any way by multiple `serialize`-`deserialize` round trips but if your use case calls for something different then I get what you're saying.